# Крашится приложение hread 1 signal sigabrt

Tags: objective-c

Стараюсь написать кнопку, по которой отправлялось бы сообщение на email, но, появляется следующая ошибка:

> thread 1 signal sigabrt

читал, что это может быть связано с *UIViewController*, но не понял где и как ее найти.

[image: перекидывает вот суда]

Ссылка на [github](https://github.com/rem0t/MusicApp/tree/MailButton/MyFirstApp) проекта.

Comment: и что делать с этим скрином? надо бы текст ошбики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контроллер не создается, поскольку устройство на котором вы запускаете приложение (симулятор) не поддерживает отправку писем. Чтобы перед переходом проверить поддерживается ли отправка писем сделайте так

```
if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
   NSLog(@"Mail services are not available.");
   return;
}
```

Comment: А как же тогда сделать чтобы поддерживало ?

Comment: Устроиться на работу в apple и переписать симулятор :)